# navicat select number of entries in one table as value in query builder

Tags: mysql, navicat

I have a current Navicat Query Builder as follows:

[image]

I want to select to select the number of records from another table that will be linked to the scoring_sections table as "num_entries" in the output results.

The table that I will be linking looks like this:

[image]

I cannot seem to figure this out as this is my first time working with navicat and couldn't find anything on Google

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to group_by all the columns from the scoring_sections  that are linked to the entries table and just added `COUNT(entries.id) AS num_entries` in the select statement. so used MYSQL knowledge to complete this